# What kind of algorithm is used to create this visual effect of "linked network nodes"?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation

What kind of algorithm is used to create the animated effect of networked nodes on the background of [this site](http://mightysignal.com/)?

I have found a similar effect in the book "Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript" titled Node Garden Mass (http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch12/08-node-garden-mass.html), but it is not quite the same.

Comment: Have you checked their source?

Answer (score 1):

This is a force directed graph

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Comment: Do you have any insight into the particular animation effect? My searches for variations on "force directed" have failed me. I have seen this effect elsewhere, but I cannot recall where.